# Interpretation of parametric differentiation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation, differential

> "How does parametric differentiation make sense both mathematically and graphically?"

I mean the method is simple to understand since one only has to differentiate both equations and divide (generally), but what does it actually mean to differentiate 2 questions and then divide them to find the differential of one with respect to another?

I've worked out the idea for the mathematical aspect and realized that $da/db$ is just a ratio so it's just the idea that $a:b = 2:3$ and $b:c = 6:11$ and if one is required to find $a:c$, he'd divide both. I think same thing holds for differentiation. But then what's the purpose of the notion familiarly stated with derivatives "derivative of one with respect to another?"

But I was struggling with the graphical interpretation, I got ideas that the graph would become a curved surface in 3D and the tangent will become a plane or that it might be related to partial derivatives and such but I think this is beyond me (class 12 student in India). A detailed explanation is welcome though.

Here's one from a snippet of a book,
“ x and y are given as functions of a single variable e.g. x =f(t) and y=g(t) are 2
functions of a single variable. In such a case x and y are called parametric functions or parametric equations and t is called the parameter. To find dy/dx in case of parametric functions, we first obtain
relationship between x and y by eliminating the parameter t and then we differentiate it with respect to x. But, it is not always convenient to eliminate the parameter. Therefore dy/dx can also be by the following formula,

$$
\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{d y / d t}{d x / d t}
$$

I have also found this alongside with it,
“To prove it, let Δx and Δy be the changes in x and y respectively corresponding to small change is Δt in t. Then,
$$
\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{\Delta y / \Delta t}{\Delta x / \Delta t} \Rightarrow \frac{d y}{d x}=\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{\lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}}{\lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}}=\frac{\frac{d y}{d t}}{\frac{d x}{d t}}
$$
So I guess, this takes care of the mathematical aspect (though I'm still not convinced with it) but what about the graphical interpretation?

Comment: Could maybe give an example of what you mean by "parametric differentiation"?

Comment: @hal4math I basically I'm speaking about the differentiation of a function with respect to another function. I've updated it as per your request…

Comment: Do you know what the chain rule is?

Comment: @hal4math Yes, I'm aware of it.

Comment: Do you also see how this is your "mathematical" justification here?

Comment: @hal4math if by 'this', you're referring to the chain rule, I apologise for failing to see it (that's probably due to my imperfect basics when it comes to fundamental proofs of calculus) but if it is the case, I'll look into it to find out more.

Comment: What you did there with the limits is really in no way more mathematical rigorous then the argument given earlier (by "Leibniz calculus") :). How does $\Delta x \to 0$ change to $\Delta t \to 0$? Really, the argument, as also given below, you are looking for is the chain rule :).

Comment: Also notice you stated the exact same thing, your just changed some names $u, v,x$ became $y,x, t$

Answer (score 1):

The "proper" way to do the things you did above. Consider the function $u(x)$. Now lets assume that $x$ is actually again a Function or something that depends on $parameter$. So in your case lets say $x = x(v)$. Now when we want to calculate the derivative of $u$ we with respect to $v$, where we need the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dv} u(x(v_0)) = \frac{du}{dx}(x(v_0)) \cdot \frac{dx}{dv}(v_0).
$$
Now, let's not evaluate the derivative, then the above expression becomes
$$
\frac{du}{dv} = \frac{du}{dx} \frac{dx}{dv}.
$$
Observe, that this last expression is a function, and so are $\frac{du}{dx}$ and $\frac{dx}{dv}$ are both functions!

Now, in the beginning of the development of calculus (e.g. the 17 century). A lot of things were not known, especially about limits and convergence and that stuff. So, when people, namely Newton and Leibniz, developed this idea of taking a derivative, they used a lot of intuition and good will. Leibniz very much argued in a similar spirit as you, say, hey look, lets denote by $du$ a very very small difference of $u$ and by $dx$ lets denote a very very small difference of $dx$, then even so these difference will super close to zero (but never really) zero, then the fraction $\frac{du}{dx}$ actually could be something meaningful and let's called it the derivative.

Today, we do not argue like this any more (at least if you are a mathematician). But Leibniz invented by this an amazing symbolism that you see in play above. Because starting from $\frac{du}{dv}$ simply by multiplying by $1 = \frac{dx}{dx}$ you actually get the chain rule effortless (as hell!). Now lets keep this idea, that $\frac{du}{dx}$ is actually a fraction, then you can also get your expression
$$
\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{dv} = \frac{\frac{du}{dx}}{\frac{dv}{dx}}
$$
and with a little bit of magic this completely unjustified manipulation of symbols actually gives the right answer (in the right circumstance!).

Maybe so much for now. Is it helpful? Not sure if I actually addressed  the question properly.

Comment: Actually I made a pretty big mistake and I am sorry that you have had to pay the price of that. In the heat of finding a source, I didn't realize the pages flipped, so I didn't imply differentiation of one function w.r.t to another rather something which is more clearly conveyed in the modified question. Again, I apologise for my negligence. However, it does use your explanation on leibnitz to justify the parametric differentiation proof, could you find something better?

Comment: Can you rephrase? What is not clear to you?

Comment: @ShreyasJV Also you might find this useful: [khanAcadamey](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-advanced-functions-new/bc-9-1/v/parametric-function-differentiation). Especially in the end, I think the graphical issue is  addressed a bit.

Comment: "today we do not argue like this anymore ( at least of you're a mathematician)" well, how would a mathematician make his argument more rigorous?

Comment: also Sal Khan uses a conventional less vigorous approach to solve this problem with a graph so I don't think the issue at hand is really cleared up.

Comment: @ShreyasJV now of course we are back to the beginning. Because as also state in the other answer: The rigorous way to understand all of this is the *chain rule*. I just added the other stuff, to maybe indicate where all of this "non rigorous approaches" might come from.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is applying the chain rule. You have (following your example), $$u=f(v),$$ where $v=g(x).$ Then of course $$u'_x=f'_vv'_x.$$

Well, in particular, for your example, since $v=\sqrt{\cos x},$ it follows that $\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\sqrt{1-v^4},$ so that $$u=\log \sqrt{1-v^4},$$ explicitly.